# What kinds of header files should not be protected against multiple inclusion?

Tags: c++, c, multiple-inclusions

I read the dcmtk source code, and found a comment in [ofstdinc.h](http://support.dcmtk.org/docs/ofstdinc_8h-source.html):

```
// this file is not and should not be protected against multiple inclusion
```

And what kinds of header files **SHOULD NOT** be protected against multiple inclusion?

Comment: The ones that are trying to use a hack (multiple inclusion) to solve a problem. In your own new code it's best to try and avoid that kind of solution and always use include guards.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Preprocessor metaprogramming. That is, using the included file as a sort of compile-time function that performs some task. The arguments to the function are macros. For example, the file you linked has a section that looks like this:

```
// define INCLUDE_STACK to include "ofstack.h"
#ifdef INCLUDE_STACK
#include "dcmtk/ofstd/ofstack.h"
#endif
```

So if I wanted to include `"ofstack.h"`, I would do so like this:

```
#define INCLUDE_STACK
#include "ofstdinc.h"
#undef INCLUDE_STACK
```

Now, imagine later down the line, someone wants to use this particular section of the header:

```
// define INCLUDE_STRING to include "ofstring.h"
#ifdef INCLUDE_STRING
#include "dcmtk/ofstd/ofstring.h"
#endif
```

So they do the following:

```
#define INCLUDE_STRING
#include "ofstdinc.h"
#undef INCLUDE_STRING
```

If `"ofstdinc.h"` had include guards, it wouldn't be included.

Comment: In instances of such headers I've seen (typically used to paste in the bodies of enums as in the other answer), the `#undefs` were within the header itself. It was thus unnecessary to duplicate the `#undef`'ing code everywhere the header is used, and it's impossible to accidentally forget to do so.

Answer (score 12):

One example are header files which expect you to define a macro. Consider a header `m.h` with

```
M( foo, "foo" )
M( bar, "bar" )
M( baz, "baz" )
```

This can be used in some other header like this:

```
#ifndef OTHER_H
#define OTHER_H

namespace other
{
    enum class my_enum
    {
#define M( k, v ) k,
#include "m.h"
#undef M
    };

    void register_my_enum();
}

#endif
```

and in some other file (possibly implementation):

```
#include "other.h"

namespace other
{
    template< typename E >
    void register_enum_string( E e, const char* s ) { ... }

    void register_my_enum()
    {
#define M( k, v ) register_enum_string( k, v );
#include "m.h"
#undef M
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, these things are sometimes known as [X macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro).

Answer (score 0):

You almost always want to protect against multiple inclusion. The only time you do not want to do so is if you are doing some fancy stuff with C macros and you therefore WANT to have multiple inclusion to get the code generation you desire (don't have an example of this offhand).